# Error 505 on servlet request

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to make a simple form but I get an error 500

index.php

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="login">
        <input type="text" name="nombre"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginServlet.java

```
package com.prueba1;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public LoginServlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>com.prueba1.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The urlpatter is set  as `/login` and the form action  is login but when I try to submit , I get an 505 error, there is no error on code and I don't know whats the problem.I've followed many tutorials and always get the same error.

this is the error , the servlet class is not found

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instanciando clase de servlet [com.prueba1.LoginServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
causa raíz

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.prueba1.LoginServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Project tree image:

[image]

Comment: did you compile your servlet ? can you check manually if the class exists under `com\prueba1` ?

Comment: the java file exists on com\prueba1 , the java file sare not compiled on click Run ass..Run on server?Do I have to do something else to compile the java files?

Answer (score -1):

Just tried to deploy and run your code on my own computer and it worked well. Make sure that your project structure is valid, you included your LoginServlet.java file into project right and that LoginServlet.class file is at the right directory after compilation. This is my project stucture:

[Make sure your class is at WEB-INF/classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2jYO.png)

[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg8Ih.png)

If you can't solve the problem, you should show your project structure after compilation. Maybe I can help you, if my screenshot will not help you. Don't forget that I'm using Maven to build the project. You structure may be a bit different.

If you are using Maven add the following lines into the dependencies block of pom.xml file:

`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

`

If not, just try to add the following line before the class declaration block:

```
@WebServlet(name="any name you want", urlPatterns="/login")
```

Comment: I've used maven, weapp archetype to build the app,and the is no .class file, I use Run as...run  on server  to run the app, do I have to do something else to compile the .java file?

Comment: I guess you are using Eclipse. I'm not strong in Eclipse, but did you try to turn on automatic build by selecting "Project -> Build Automatically"?

Comment: Build automatically option is selected

Comment: Can't give you any more advises without screenshot of your project structure

Comment: I've posted the project structure on the first post

Comment: There is no file LoginServlet.java in com.prueba. The file must be named the same as the classname of a public class